# Unable to use COM service events via python

Tags: c#, python, events, com, win32com

I have problem with using events from some windows service (i don't have access to source code, i have only documentation). One of events is defined (in documentation) as (C#):

```
public event BarcodeScanEventHandler OnBarcodeScanned
```

Where `BarcodeScanEventHandler`:

```
public delegate void BarcodeScanEventHandler( Object sender, BarcodeScanEventArgs args )
```

Let me show you a minimized example:

```
import win32com.client
cls="FooService"

api = win32com.client.Dispatch(cls)

class ApiEvents:
    def OnBarcodeScanned(self, value): #doesnt matter if its OnBarcodeScanned(self) or OnBarcodeScanned(self, value1, value2)
        print(" * Barcode scanned!")

api.Initialize()
events = win32com.client.WithEvents(api, ApiEvents)
```

What throws error:

```
  File "minevents", line 14, in <module>
    events = win32com.client.WithEvents(api, ApiEvent
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client
 WithEvents
    raise ValueError("This COM object does not suppor
ValueError: This COM object does not support events.
```

I have tried to google it but there is no usefull information. After that i tried another library `comtypes` with following code:

```
import comtypes.client
api = comtypes.clientCreateObject("FooService")
comtypes.client.ShowEvents(api)
```

But it throws error:

```
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    comtypes.client.ShowEvents(api)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_events.py", line 218, in ShowEvents
    return comtypes.client.GetEvents(source, sink=EventDumper(), interface=interface)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_events.py", line 193, in GetEvents
    interface = FindOutgoingInterface(source)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_events.py", line 62, in FindOutgoingInterface
    interface = comtypes.com_coclass_registry[clsid]._outgoing_interfaces_[0]
AttributeError: type object 'FooService' has no attribute '_outgoing_interfaces_'
```

I also tried `help(api)` and there are some interesting functions:

```
 |  add_OnBarcodeScanned(...)
 |  remove_OnBarcodeScanned(...)
```

I tried to call `add_OnBarcodeScanned`:

```
class BarcodeScanned(object):
    def QueryInterface(self, value):
        help(value)

barcodeScanned = BarcodeScanned()
api.add_OnBarcodeScanned(barcodeScanned)
```

What gives me `IUnknown`:

```
class IUnknown(__builtin__.object)
 |  The most basic COM interface.
 |  
 |  Each subclasses of IUnknown must define these class attributes:
 |  
 |  _iid_ - a GUID instance defining the identifier of this interface
 |  
 |  _methods_ - a list of methods for this interface.
 |  
 |  The _methods_ list must in VTable order.  Methods are specified
 |  with STDMETHOD or COMMETHOD calls.
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  AddRef(self)
 |      Increase the internal refcount by one and return it.
 |  
 |  QueryInterface(self, interface, iid=None)
 |      QueryInterface(interface) -> instance
 |  
 |  Release(self)
 |      Decrease the internal refcount by one and return it.
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |  
 |  __metaclass__ = <class 'comtypes._cominterface_meta'>
 |      Metaclass for COM interfaces.  Automatically creates high level
 |      methods from COMMETHOD lists.
```

Now i have no idea what should i do. Am i doing something wrong? But you should know that all following code works with `InternetExplorer.Application`. Is there something wrong with this service? Or do you have idea how should i do with method `add_OnBarcodeScanned` to call my python method/class if event will be triggered?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Pakman from what I remember I was digging really deep i wrote my own little lib to work with COM services. Last guess was that there was something wrong with COM library. Finally i was unable to use that lib. :(